# Is it valid to calculate Spearman/Cramér's V with duplicate values?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, spearman-rho, sentiment-analysis, cramers-v

I have a dataset that I want to analyze using statistic measures. Because of the nature of the data, it seems like Cramér's V is the correct method (For cases involving (school) grades only, Spearman may be correct. I use both depending on the data). In my scenario here, users assign  school grades and write additional evaluative texts. I want to analyze the grades assigned together with the corresponding texts. To do that, I have extracted the sentiment phrases from the texts. I now have:

1. Average school grades assigned by Internet users to certain objects (e.g. to movies), i.e. 1 grade per movie
2. average polarity values of the phrases users write in their texts to asses objects (like a movie), i.e. n sentiment polarity values per movie (sentiment scores are positive or negative, can be seen as 0 and 1)

To calculate Cramér's V, I build a table where I have to copy the school grades as often as there are polarity scores:

| Overall grades | Sentiment polarity per phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 2,7 | negative |
| 2,7 | positive |
| 2,7 | negative |
| 1,5 | positive |
| 1,5 | positive |

Is it **valid** to basically duplicate the overall grades in order to match them with the existing sentiment polarity values or am I overthinking here? How can this question be answered regarding a Spearman Correlation?